# Variables in script do not show in Inspector (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to learn how to use Unity and following online tutorials but I am currently having a problem that I don't understand how to fix.

I have a Sprite in my scene and I have attached a script to it however in the Inspector it shows the script is there but I cannot see the variables inside? I had this problem previously and it sorted itself out.

What is the cause of this problem/how do I fix it?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpaceShip : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed = 30;

    public GameObject theBullet;

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float horzMove = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(horzMove, 0) * 
            speed;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            Instantiate(theBullet, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Better use f to represent float data types. speed = 30.0f

Comment: please include a screenshot of the inspector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: The problem was solved by reimporting.

You either need to declare the variables as `Public` or `[SerializeField]` for member variables to appear in the inspector. Note that by declaring something as public allows access to the variable from outside the class (from other scripts/classes for example). By default, `private` is assigned to member variables.

Example:

```
public class testscript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int foo; // shows up in inspector
    [SerializeField] private int bar; // also shows up while still being private

    void Start()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I should have posted code originally. I have added code now. My variables are already public but only the speed variable shows up in my Inspector

Comment: are you getting any errors? I don't see a reason why `theBullet` wouldn't show up as well. I tried your code in my own script and it works fine (speed and bullet both show in inspector). make sure you save the script of course.

Comment: I have them both showing now. I clicked reimport on my script in Unity and it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Not is a problem, You forget to do something surely.

It is common at first with Unity.

Start again.

In the scene create a new GameObject and add you script.

If the inspector shows not variable:

1. The varible do not is public (false, if is public in you script)
2. There is some syntax error in the script!

or

3. You were not adding the correct script to the GameObject.

There are not many secrets to that, if all is well enough that the variable is public and this outside of a method of the script so that it is seen in the inspector.

One tip, do not use a GetComponent or Instantiate inside a FixedUpdate or Update because they are expensive, save the Rigidbody2D in a variable in the Start and then use it.

Sorry for my English and good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it happens when you have some errors in your code and it wont show up in the console. TO fix it close and open the unity editor again and it asks whether if we wanna enter into safe mode to fix those errors. After fixing it in safe mode it automatically turns off and goes to normal mode and shows up the variables in the inspector.